# Apache KeepAlive with Cloudflare

Tags: apache-2.4, cloudflare

I use Cloudflare with WAF enabled.

My Apache server that is called by Cloudflare has KeepAlive enabled.

But from what I understand, KeepAlive will keep active connections for existing users, but since Cloudflare sends the same request from a user through different IPs it seems to me that it will not be able to detect that it is the same user.

So my question is, should I still keep KeepAlive enabled on my Apache server?

This is Apache config:

```
MaxKeepAliveRequests 150
KeepAliveTimeout 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In cloudflare community they said to keep KeepAlive enable with 900s.
But I try it and it did convince me.